# php cURL doesn't follow redirect

Tags: php, redirect, curl, http-status-codes

I use the following code to get the http-status code of the final URL (after following all redirects):

```
$handle = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
            // we want headers
            //curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'my bot');
            $response = curl_exec($handle);
            $httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            curl_close($handle);
```

However, cURL doesn't follow the redirects. F.e. if I use www.raffiniert.biz/kunden, it shows a plain 301, instead of following to www.raffiniert.biz/kunden/

What's wrong?

Thanks
Raphael

Comment: Are you sure this is an http redirect? cURL only follows https redirects - not meta and js redirects.

Comment: I am relatively sure, as in firebug, you don't see anything of the redirect - have a look for yourself!

Comment: I only got an 403 Forbidden..

Comment: I just tried the exact code with the provided URL and it worked for me, although I received a 403 forbidden response. Maybe you need to increase your max_redirects header

Comment: yes, and that's correct. However, cURL in PHP gives a 301 when you use "/kunden" instead of "/kunden/"

Answer (score 0):

I got expected response using exactly the same as your code.

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 01 Dec 2014 23:19:56 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 309
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://www.raffiniert.biz/kunden/
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Expires: Mon, 01 Dec 2014 23:19:56 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 01 Dec 2014 23:19:57 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 277
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /kunden/
on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache Server at www.raffiniert.biz Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

---

You have to check...

```
error_reporting(-1);
```

or

```
if (ini_get('safe_mode') || (string)ini_get('open_basedir') !== '') {
    exit('You have no permission to set CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION');
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I see that open_basedir is set - is there a way to deactivate it only for that sub-folder on my server?

Comment: You could try changing the value with `ini_set()`, but you could also try follow the redirection manually by scanning with PHP for a new url (Location header) in the response header and then re-do the cURL with the new URL.